# Breakpoints with PHP

Tags: php, loops, events, command-line-interface

My script, which is running from the command line, is doing lots of DB and API calls inside a loop but to test I have to change conditions and place `die()` and run the script over and over again.

Is there any way to advance the iteration only on pressing `Return`, end the script execution on pressing `Esc`, otherwise just wait it until either of the above input events occur?

```
$arr = range(0, 10000);

foreach ($arr as $n) {
    // if ENTER
    echo $n;
    // elseif ESC 
    die()
    // else 
    // wait for ENTER or ESC
}
```

Comment: You could place an error_log() in the loop or try catch and log exceptions in order to see what's happening.  If that's what you're trying to achieve by pausing code if event happens.  Other way could be to use an IDE such as XDebug where you could place a breakpoint in your code and step through it line by line.

Comment: @mrjamesmyers No, not errors, just execution. So each iteration I need to check if everything is alright, press ENTER, advance to the next ... and so on.

Comment: You could achieve that using XDebug which can be configured to work with NetBeans, Notepad++ and many other IDE's/Editors (or PHPStorm or Zend Studio but have to pay for them).  Other wise could do a foreach loop in JavaScript then listen to Enter Key press and increment index then use Ajax to post to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late to this question, but here is a method you can use. The only drawback is that it doesn't work exactly as requested. To continue the loop, press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. To exit the loop you have to type `exit`, followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```
<?php

$arr = range(0, 10000);
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");

foreach ($arr as $n) {
    $line = fgets($handle);

    // if user types "exit" and ENTER
    if (trim($line) == "exit") {
        die();
    }

    echo $n;

    // Do DB and API calls here

}
```